# How to use PerformSegueForIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I am fresh in iOS and objective-c. I am learning how to use segues, especially unwind segue.

while reading, I got a bit confused about the usage of 'shouldPerformSegueForIdentifier' and 'performSegueForIdentifier'.

I created an example contains two 'ViewControllers', 'ViewController.m' as shown in the code posted below 'VC_1' and 'ServiceViewController'

my questions are:

-when and how should I use 'performSegueForIdentifier'

-when and how should I use 'shouldIPerformSegueForIdentifier'?

**VC_1**:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ServiceViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a    
 nib.
 }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)btnStartService:(UIButton *)sender {
   if (sender.tag == 1) {
    NSLog(@"CLICKED");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seguePassInterval" sender:(id)   
sender];
}
}

-(IBAction)btnExitApp:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"EXIT_CLICKED");

}



 - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"seguePassInterval"]) {
    ((ServiceViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).data = @"testData"; //passing data to destinationViewController of type "TestViewController"
    NSLog(@"SEGUE");
}

}


@end
```

**img**

[image]

Comment: For shouldPerformSegueForIdentifier it is Determines whether the segue with the specified identifier should be performed. and for performSegueForIdentifier using it you can pass the data from one VC to another

Comment: can you please provide an example how to use shouldPerformSegueForIdentifier?

Comment: when you call performSegueWithIdentifier yourself, shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier is not called because it can be assumed that you know what you are doing. there would be no point in calling performSegueWithIdentifier but then return a NO from shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepareForSegue` method is called right before the segue is executed, and allow to pass data between `ViewController` among other things, you can by example check if the identifier of your segue is "XxX" and pass some data or if is "YYY" call for a method

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"seguePassInterval"]) {
    ((TestViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).data = @"testData"; //passing data to destinationViewController of type "TestViewController"
    NSLog(@"SEGUE");
}
}
```

method `performSegueWithIdentifier` is used to as his name says execute a segue using his identifier, you can perform a segue when you need it

and finally `shouldPerformSegue` is used to avoid perform a segue if your app is in some state, for example if you don't have the `destinationViewController` data yet you can return false until you get that

Hope this helps

Comment: 1st.DestinationViewController is undefined. 2nd.since prepareForSegue will be called automatically whether initiating the segue is a button or a cell, why do we need performSegueForIdentifier?

Comment: @user2121 TestViewController is a example, must be your destinationViewController class name, performSegueForIdentifier execute the segue after that the prepareForSegue is called, check my edited answer

Comment: thanks, but how can I receive the data in the destinationViewController

Comment: @user2121 you need declare the data variable in your destinationViewController in my example you need declare data as String in  the `TestViewController` declaration, so when prepareForSegue method is called the data is passed and when TestViewController is presented in data will have the value passed in my example the string  ¨testData¨ hope this helps

Comment: I added 'data' as a property in destinationVieController.h as NSString*..but I string I receive the error shown in the image posted above

Comment: @user2121 add #import ServiceViewController.h in your .m and let me know should work

Comment: @service.h is imported in servcice.m and I still receive the the error in the image +1

Comment: @user2121 you need import   ServiceViewController.h  in your ViewController.m i will edit your question